# Computer is unreachable on wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, ping

I have a Dell Precision Laptop with Windows 10, it's my work computer and used to be able to be reached by other computers on the same network.

During one of the projects I worked at, our client required us to have our computers configured by their IT team to have Checkpoint Endpoint Security VPN Client.

It seems they did something else to our configuration, ever since, our computers are unreachable on a wireless connection, a ping to my computer from a different one returns timeout.

I tested wiring through an Ethernet connection to another computer and then I could reach my computer with no problem, so the issue lies when it's connected through wireless.

Does anyone what could they have done to my computer to make it unreachable on a wireless network connection?

**EDIT**

I just noticed, on the Network and Sharing Center, under the network name it says private network, also on the network properties window I have the option "make this pc discoverable" switched on, does this give more insight into my issue?

Comment: what IP address ranges are you getting on your wired vs wireless NICs? are they in the same range?

Comment: I tried to connect my computer with another one through an Ethernet wire, I set the IP on both and could ping between the two computers, on wireless they're on the same subnet range and I can ping other computers on the same network but none of them can ping to my computer.

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings and make sure that ICMP is not disabled for the network type that wireless is using? I would also verify that wired and wireless are using the same connection type i.e. home or public

Comment: the firewall on my computer is turned off, where do I check the ICMP? This issue is only present in my computer and my coworkers who worked on the same project and had their computers tampered by our business client's IT team, where can I verify if it's public or home? Checked the WiFi network properties but didn't see it there.